# FileSystemWatcher not triggering action block on event

Tags: git, powershell

I have a file I need to push to a Git repo as soon as it gets written to and I've knocked up the script below to achieve this. The event gets created fine but doesn't execute the code block when I write to the file, and I'm not sure why.

The script:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Path\To\Repo"
$watcher.Filter = "file.txt"
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {
    Set-Location $watcher.Path

    # random alphanumeric string to populate the commit name
    $rand = -join ((65..90) + (97..122) | Get-Random -Count 16 | % {[char]$_})

    Write-Host "File pwds.kdb has been updated. Committing to git..."

    git add .
    git commit -m "$rand"
    git push

    if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "Pushed to repo successfully"
    }
}
```

The output of `Register-ObjectEvent`:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
18     FileChanged                     NotStarted    False                                ...
```

with `$(Get-EventSubscriber -SubscriptionId 18).Action.Command` being the contents of the action block.

Two things to note:

- The "HasMoreData" attribute does not update to "True" after I write to the file, which could indicate it's not picking up the change properly?
- The "State" attribute says "NotStarted"

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'lastaccess,filename'
```

I dont know whether it is works or not,Just try it